# Using PagedList in partial views in MVC 4 is throwing off jQuery/JS when navigating 'paged' pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just implemented paging using PagedList in my MVC 4 application. The homepage of my app contains a partial view that displays a list of summarised data about certain objects. Beside each list item is a button that when clicked launches a modal window, displaying more information about that particular list item.

All works well on the first 'paged' page of list items, however if I navigate to the second 'paged' page and click the button to launch modal nothing happens. From developer tools in Chrome I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'`.

The partial in question outputs the list, contains the DIV for the modal and a JS function to handle the button click event that launches modal windows. Here's the JS from that partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.show-modal').click(function () {
        var url = $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').attr('data-url');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#view-property-from-get-all-container').html(data);
            $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I navigate back to the first 'paged' page, the button doesn't fire either and same uncaught typeError is thrown. Another jQuery plugin I use that truncates multi-line text also stops working and text overflows its containing DIV.

1. What's actually happening here - why does using paging interfere with JS like this?
2. How can I resolve this?

**EDIT:**

All records of particular type are returned from controller action:

```
return PartialView("_GetAllPropertiesPartial", model.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Since it's a partial, paging navigation is handled by `Ajax.ActionLinks()`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("<<", "GetAllProperties", new { page = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "quick-property-search-results" })
```

Comment: When you navigate to the second page, is there an Ajax request that loads this page? or is everything loaded upon the first page render and then paged on the client side?

Comment: Yes, Ajax.ActionLink handles navigation since I'm using partial views.  Please see edit.

Comment: The $('.show-modal') event handler is only being bound upon document.ready, this means that any dom elements created after that (such as the ones being created on the second page load) are not going to have that binding. Try using .live('click', function) instead of .click(function)

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, and I'm getting "object has no method live". It has been completely removed from 1.9+. I tried .bind() and .on(), still no joy.

Comment: Sorry, the method changed on the latest jQuery releases! .on() should work. Take a look at @Tieson's answer. If you still have troubles try and setup a jsfiddle so we can look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the event handler to something that doesn't get replaced in your markup, and use the `.on()` method rather than `.click()`, like so:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.show-modal', function (e) {
        var url = $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').attr('data-url');
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
            $('#view-property-from-get-all-container').html(data);
            $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You can use something other than `body` if you have a parent element that you know won't get replaced. It's also worth noting that you could be using `.load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#view-property-from-get-all-container').load(url + '/' + id, function (response, status, jqxhr) {
    // this is an optional callback
    $('#modal-view-property-from-get-all').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting that uncaught type error for .modal. Though I think it is making a difference because I'm getting an alert that comes from another partial that contains the modal body etc. I have the above script in a partial, would it make a difference to move it to my site.js file?

Comment: @MattSull87 Without seeing how your code is setup, it's hard to say, but as a rule it does seem to work out better if you have your scripts in, say, `_Layout` or in the `scripts` section of the "normal" view (for me, at any rate).

Comment: Is there any additional code I can provide that might assist you?

Comment: @MattSull87 Assuming you have Firebug or something similar, try adding a `console.log($('#modal-view-property-from-get-all'));` somewhere in the callback of your `.get()`. If the output is "undefined" it means jQuery could not find the targeted element, so you're trying to call `.modal()` on a `null` object.

Comment: I did as you suggested - in the first page of results, modal opens correctly, no error in console in Chrome. On the second page, on button click, in the console it's the same uncaughtType Error. One button click makes the error fire twice for some reason. If I'm not getting an "undefined" what does that suggest?

Comment: @MattSull87 Multiple errors generally indicate that multiple delegates have been assigned to the event that you're targeting. This can happen if you have the same chunk of jQuery in both the parent and the partial view. If you can post a simplified version of the markup of your layout, view, and partial view to something like Pastebin or Collabedit it may help make the error more obvious; otherwise, I'm just guessing here, since nothing in what you posted stands out as inherently wrong.

Comment: I've created a Collabedit http://collabedit.com/9wx87 (with comments) Apologies for not getting back to you sooner - I've been busy wrapping this project up for submission. I'd really appreciate if you could have a look. If you need any more information just ask.

Comment: @MattSull87 Hmm. I haven't used the `Ajax` helpers myself, but I have to believe the partial refresh those links are causing are the most likely root cause. I'll have to see if I can come up with an example (based on your code) that works. I think I know the problem, but I want to verify first...

Comment: That's great, hope you figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Finally figured out what the problem was: I had an additional reference to jQuery in a partial view that's involved with a GET, so when an additional GET happens i.e. navigating pages, what's initially bound to jQuery isn't any more. It's always the simple things. I'll mark your answer as correct - thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattSull87 Awesome. It's worth noting that you can add your own answer and accept it, since you found the root cause yourself.

Comment: I could, but you may as well get the extra rep.